# Oracle APEX - how to call a javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, oracle-apex

I'd like to call a function based on a text input. This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <style>
        .message {
            margin-top: 10px;
            color: red;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>   
    <div id="uppercase" class="message">Must contain at least one uppercase letter</div>
    <div id="lowercase" class="message">Must contain at least one lowercase letter</div>
    <div id="numeric" class="message">Must contain at least one numeric digit</div>
    <div id="specialchar" class="message">Must contain at least one special character</div>
    
    <script>
        function checkPassword() {
            var password = document.getElementById("P99_NEW_PASSWORD").value;
            var uppercaseMessage = document.getElementById("uppercase");
            var lowercaseMessage = document.getElementById("lowercase");
            var numericMessage = document.getElementById("numeric");
            var specialcharMessage = document.getElementById("specialchar");

            // Reset messages
            uppercaseMessage.style.color = "red";
            lowercaseMessage.style.color = "red";
            numericMessage.style.color = "red";
            specialcharMessage.style.color = "red";

            // Check conditions
            if (/[A-Z]/.test(password)) {
                uppercaseMessage.style.color = "green";
            }
            if (/[a-z]/.test(password)) {
                lowercaseMessage.style.color = "green";
            }
            if (/\d/.test(password)) {
                numericMessage.style.color = "green";
            }
            if (/[!@#$%^&*(),.?":{}|<>]/.test(password)) {
                specialcharMessage.style.color = "green";
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is how it looks like:
[image]

What I want to do is, when a user enter a password in the New Password field (which is P99_NEW_PASSWORD), checkPassword() will be called. However, I don't know what/where to put to call checkPassword() function.
Could anyone help to solve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: where have you added above html in the page?

Comment: I've added it to P99_NEW_PASSWORD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example for a single message, my page is 206:

1. Create javascript function in Page Attributes > Function and Global Variable Declaration

```
        function checkPassword() {
            var password = apex.items.P206_NEW_PASSWORD.getValue();
            var uppercaseMessage = document.getElementById("uppercase");

            // Reset messages
            uppercaseMessage.style.color = "red";

            // Check conditions
            if (/[A-Z]/.test(password)) {
                uppercaseMessage.style.color = "green";
            }
        }
```

2. For testing only, the message is displayed as "Post Text" in the page item, source:

```
<div id="uppercase">Must Contain at least one uppercase letter</div>
```

For UI purposes, this can probably be done cleaner using the same source.

3. Create a dynamic action on change of P206_NEW_PASSWORD.

- Add a true action of type "Execute Javascript Code"
- Code

```
checkPassword()
```

- Uncheck "Fire on initialization"

Note: it's fine for code like this to check: the user knows the new password and can check it. However, for any password saving, comparing and validating... that should *always* be done encrypted and not in clear text. In general it's pretty unusual for apex applications to have their own user management. There are plenty of options for credential management.